# Understanding generics and how type checking works

Tags: java, android, generics

How does the datatype checking in a generic collection happen ? For example, take a look at the ArrayList below :

```
ArrayList<String> r1 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
r1.add("4");
r1.add("1");
r1.add("2");
r1.add("3");
```

How is the `ArrayList<String>` linked to the method `add()` ?  If I were to create my own class which is not a collection, how do i tie the generics parameter to make sure strict type checking occurs ?

Another example I observed in Android with the AsyncTask class :

```
private class SomeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {
```

where String refers to the input, Integer to the progress and Long to the response. Where is this mapping done ? How do i create my own generic class and where do i define this mapping ?

Comment: Addition to the answers: the type checking is only done by the compiler. No check is done at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First question**

Take a look at the [Generic Types Tutorial for Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). An example might clarify this:

```
public class Tuple<X, Y> {

   X first;
   Y second;

   public Tuple(X first, Y second) {
      this.first = first;    
      this.second = second;
   }
}
```

When you instantiate this class, you could do it for instance with the following line:

`Tuple<String, Integer> tuple = new Tuple<String, Integer>("Hello", 1);`

and the type parameter check is done here during compile time, since the constructor expects now `String` and an `Integer` as parameter (in this order).

**Second question**

I hope the tuple example already made clear how the mapping can be accomplished: with different generic type parameter names.

The same is done in the case of `AsyncTask` in the type parameter definition, different  names are used, for instance: `AsyncTask<A, B, C>` and thus they can be discriminated when applying each of them.

For that take a look at the [source code of AsyncTask](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/os/AsyncTask.java/?v=source), where the class is defined as:

```
public abstract class AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```

The type parameter name does not have to be a single letter, it can also be a whole name.

Comment: I instantiated ArrayList<String>() with no parameters. But how does the ArrayList class know that the type checking should be done in the add() method. What if i have a method that converts a string to an object and I dont require type checking ? Where is this checking done ?

Comment: @WarDoGG Do you mean invoking `new ArrayList()`, thus omitting the generic type parameter? The result is a list with the raw type. There is **no type safety with raw types**, hence no checking is done. You can read more on this topic in the answer to the following question [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: @WarDoGG Regarding your method which converts a `String` to an `Object`: I cannot answer this in general without knowing the use case or what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

It is of my opinion that Generics is too much of a broad subject to be covered decently as a response. I would recommend you start by taking a look at Oracle's tutorial ([here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)) for all the information you should need.

That being said, as a quick answer, the `.add()` method, as per [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html), takes a generic parameter `E`, which is the same parameter specified when the list is created, in your case this being a string.

Secondly, to create your own generic class, it is as simple as doing something like so:

```
public MyClass<T>
{
    private T myT;

    public void set(T t)
    {
        this.myT = t;
    }

    public T get()
    {
       return this.myT;
    }
}
```

In the case above, `T` refers to the generic parameter. The parameter is set when you instantiate your class, such as `... new MyClass<String>();`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a generic class that has a `doSomething` method, you could write it:

```
class GenericClass<E> {
    public void doSomething(E aThing) {
       //do something with aThing
    }
}
```

You can now use it "like" an arraylist:

```
GenericClass<String> myGeneric = new GenericClass<String>();
myGeneric.doSomething("abc");

GenericClass<Integer> myGeneric2 = new GenericClass<Integer>();
myGeneric.doSomething(123);
```

Now if you want to know more about how ArrayList is implemented, the best thing to do is [to check the code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html).